# Show Grid under Custom Tab in CMS Page Information Section in Magento Admin

Tags: magento-1.7, module

I have made a custom module in magento admin. In which I am showing a custom tab on CMS page area as shown in below image.

[image]

I have a custom form on click on "My Button". I fill that form and value is properly inserted in DB.

Now I want to show Grid for saved data under my custom tab for that form.

How can I do this on CMS Page area in Magento admin..?

Please help me to get rid of this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can Call another Grid Via 2 Ways. Hope You know the whole structure of Magento Grid Management.

**Step 1:**  Open your Module Folder like `[NameSpace]\[Module Name]\Block\Adminhtml\[modulename]\Edit\Tabs.php`.

**Step 2:** In `_beforeToHtml()` Method add last Below Code.

```
  $this->addTab("Custom Block", array(
        "label" => Mage::helper("custom")->__("Custom Block"),
        "title" => Mage::helper("reordermanagement")->__("Custom Block"),
        'content' => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('[modulename]/adminhtml_[anothermoduleanme]_grid', 'custom-tab-content')->toHtml(),            
        'class' => 'ajax'
    ));
```

**Step 3:** This is one Way to add the Custom grid to another tab grid.

Or

**Step2:** Another Way is to create a `action` in controller.

**Step 3:** Add Below Code.

```
$this->addTab("reorder History", array(
        "label" => Mage::helper("reordermanagement")->__("Reorder History"),
        "title" => Mage::helper("reordermanagement")->__("Reorder History"),            
        'url'=>$this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true)),
        'class' => 'ajax'
    ));
```

**Step 4:** Create `gridAction()` Method in `[Namespace]\[Module Name]\controllers\Adminhtml\yourController.php` and create Below Method.

```
 public function gridAction()
 {
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(
        Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('[modulename]/adminhtml_[anothermoduleanme]_grid')->toHtml()
    );
}
```

These are the simple steps to add Grid into Custom tab.

Comment: Hello @keyul, I have no file named "Tabs.php" at location specified by you. I want to tell you that I have created custom tab with xml file in layout in adminhtml folder.

Comment: Then you have to change the logic to add the tab and you have to over ride the core class and added your code

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what part of the code you already have, here a complete walk-thru on how to add a grid to the CMS Page edit:

I named my example Example_CmsTabGrid:

Module init file:
/app/etc/modules/Example_CmsTabGrid.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Example_CmsTabGrid>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Example_CmsTabGrid>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Module config file:
/app/code/community/Example/CmsTabGrid/etc/config.xml:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Example_CmsTabGrid>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Example_CmsTabGrid>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <example_cmstabgrid>
                <class>Example_CmsTabGrid_Block</class>
            </example_cmstabgrid>
        </blocks>

        <helpers>
            <example_cmstabgrid>
                <class>Example_CmsTabGrid_Helper</class>
            </example_cmstabgrid>
        </helpers>
    </global>

    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <example_cmstabgrid>
                    <file>example_cmstabgrid.xml</file>
                </example_cmstabgrid>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Helper:
/app/code/community/Example/CmsTabGrid/Helper/Data.php:

```
<?php

class Example_CmsTabGrid_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

Layout file to add tab to cms_page_edit:
/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/example_cmstabgrid.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_cms_page_edit>
        <reference name="cms_page_edit_tabs">
            <action method="addTab">
                <name>example_cmstabgrid</name>
                <block>example_cmstabgrid/cms_page_edit_tab_grid</block>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_cms_page_edit>
</layout>
```

And the last file that combines the Tab interface with the Grid combined:
/app/code/community/Example/CmsTabGrid/Block/Cms/Page/Edit/Tab/Grid.php:

```
<?php

class Example_CmsTabGrid_Block_Cms_Page_Edit_Tab_Grid
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
{

    /**
     * Get tab label
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return Mage::helper('example_cmstabgrid')->__('Blocks');
    }

    /**
     * Get tab title
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return Mage::helper('example_cmstabgrid')->__('Blocks');
    }

    /**
     * Check if tab can be displayed
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Check if tab is hidden
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('myTabGrid');
        $this->setUseAjax(false);
        $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setEmptyText(Mage::helper('example_cmstabgrid')->__('No records found!'));
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('cms/block')
            ->getCollection();

        $this->setCollection($collection);

        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {

        $this->addColumn(
            'identifier',
            array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('example_cmstabgrid')->__('Identifier'),
                'width' => '200px',
                'index' => 'identifier',
            )
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'is_active',
            array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('example_cmstabgrid')->__('Active'),
                'index' => 'is_active',
                'type' => 'options',
                'options' => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno')->toArray(),
            )
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'title',
            array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('example_cmstabgrid')->__('Title'),
                'index' => 'title',
            )
        );


    }

    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Hope this helps you with what you are looking for.

Comment: very detailed answer (y)